# jpql query not working in time compare

Tags: java, jpa

```
select ticktime from stocktechnicaldataentity where
ticktime::time>'09:30:00.000' AND ticktime::time<'15:00:00.000' limit 50;
```

when i use this query in postgresql it give proper result when i use this query in jpql it not working.

JPQL query-

```
 String sql1="select tickTime from stocktechnicaldataentity where  
        tickTime::time>'09:30:00.000' AND tickTime::time<'15:00:00.000' limit 50";
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sql1);
List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
```

Give the error

> Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.6.4.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select tickTime from
>   stocktechnicaldataentity where  tickTime::time>'09:30:00.000' AND
>   tickTime::time<'15:00:00.000' limit 50].

Comment: try `createNativeQuery`

Comment: And have you not thought that JPQL != SQL? Any glance through a JPQL syntax documentation would tell you that it has certain syntax and functions and they are different from SQL.